# Best practices for index/fulltext when using WHERE/LIKE

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause, full-text-indexing

Should I set the columns to in my table as index or fulltext? They will be searched for both using WHERE and WHERE .. LIKE.

Which is best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full-text searches require different syntax from normal LIKE queries.  If you're using LIKE queries (and don't plan on modifying them) you will only get a benefit from using nonclustered indexes.  If you are interested in using full-text search, consider using the MATCH() syntax in your queries.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html